# Does html5 link prefetch affect Google Analytics?

Tags: html, google-analytics, meta-tags, prefetch

Does the [html5 link prefetch attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch) cause a visit to be counted on the prefetched page in Google Analytics?

`<link rel="prefetch" href="http://someurl.com/page.htm" />`

This [SO question about tracking prefetched AJAX content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705389/does-preloading-content-from-a-page-skew-my-google-analytics-stats) is similar but the `<link>` tag is a browser interpretation without any Javascript and it is implemented per browser.

I am developing sites with logical previous and next page content. The application is browsing sequentially through a website, training course or online brochure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prefetch only downloads the resources, but does not execute the code, or fire DOM events or so.

Given Google Analytics depends on running JS, I don't expect it to be affected.

Any server side analytics that track requests to the given resources will be affected though.